# How To Set Up Byte Alignment From a MTLBuffer to a 2D MTLTexture?

Tags: cocoa, metal, metalkit, mtlbuffer

I have an array of float values that represents a 2D image (think from a CCD) that I ultimately want to render into a `MTLView`. This is on macOS, but I'd like to be able to apply the same to iOS at some point. I initially create an `MTLBuffer` with the data:

```c
NSData *floatData = ...;
id<MTLBuffer> metalBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytes:floatData.bytes
                                                length:floatData.length
                                               options:MTLResourceCPUCacheModeDefaultCache | MTLResourceStorageModeManaged];
```

From here, I run the buffer through a few compute pipelines. Next, I want to create an RGB `MTLTexture` object to pass to a few `CIFilter`/MPS filters and then display. It seems to make sense to create a texture that uses the already created buffer as backing to avoid making another copy. (I've successfully used textures with a pixel format of `MTLPixelFormatR32Float`.)

```c
// create texture with scaled buffer - this is a wrapper, i.e. it shares memory with the buffer
MTLTextureDescriptor *desc;
desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR32Float
                                                          width:width
                                                         height:height
                                                      mipmapped:NO];
desc.usage = MTLResourceUsageRead;
desc.storageMode = scaledBuffer.storageMode; // must match buffer

id<MTLTexture> scaledTexture = [scaledBuffer newTextureWithDescriptor:desc
                                                               offset:0 
                                                          bytesPerRow:imageWidth * sizeof(float)];
```

The image dimensions are 242x242. When I run this I get:

```
validateNewTexture:89: failed assertion `BytesPerRow of a buffer-backed
texture with pixelFormat(MTLPixelFormatR32Float) must be aligned to 256 bytes,
found bytesPerRow(968)'
```

I know I need to use:

```c
NSUInteger alignmentBytes = [self.device minimumLinearTextureAlignmentForPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR32Float];
```

How do I define the buffer such that the bytes are properly aligned?

More generally, is this the appropriate approach for this kind of data? This is the stage where I effectively convert the float data into something that has color. To clarify, this is my next step:

```c
// render into RGB texture
MPSImageConversion *imageConversion = [[MPSImageConversion alloc] initWithDevice:self.device
                                                                        srcAlpha:MPSAlphaTypeAlphaIsOne
                                                                       destAlpha:MPSAlphaTypeAlphaIsOne
                                                                 backgroundColor:nil
                                                                  conversionInfo:NULL];
[imageConversion encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer
                           sourceImage:scaledTexture
                      destinationImage:intermediateRGBTexture];
```

where `intermediateRGBTexture` is a 2D texture defined with `MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float` to take advantage of EDR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's important to you that the texture share the same backing memory as the buffer, and you want the texture to reflect the actual image dimensions, you need to ensure that the data in the buffer is correctly aligned from the start.

Rather than copying the source data all at once, you need to ensure the buffer has room for all of the aligned data, then copy it one row at a time.

```
NSUInteger rowAlignment = [self.device minimumLinearTextureAlignmentForPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR32Float];
NSUInteger sourceBytesPerRow = imageWidth * sizeof(float);
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = AlignUp(sourceBytesPerRow, rowAlignment);
id<MTLBuffer> metalBuffer = [self.device newBufferWithLength:bytesPerRow * imageHeight
                                                     options:MTLResourceCPUCacheModeDefaultCache];

const uint8_t *sourceData = floatData.bytes;
uint8_t *bufferData = metalBuffer.contents;
for (int i = 0; i < imageHeight; ++i) {
    memcpy(bufferData + (i * bytesPerRow), sourceData + (i * sourceBytesPerRow), sourceBytesPerRow);
}
```

Where `AlignUp` is your alignment function or macro of choice. Something like this:

```
static inline NSUInteger AlignUp(NSUInteger n, NSInteger alignment) {
    return ((n + alignment - 1) / alignment) * alignment;
}
```

It's up to you to determine whether the added complexity is worth saving a copy, but this is one way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply (and your other extremely helpful SO answers & tutorials!). I implemented this but I think there are two bugs, both in the `memcpy` command (I was getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). Since the data arrays are declared as `float*`, `bytesPerRow` and `sourceBytesPerRow` should be divided by 4 (the pointer arithmetic takes into account the float size). And I think the last parameter should be `sourceBytesPerRow`? When I run this I get `source 0x… may have no more than 4 feature channels for MPSUnaryImageKernels` when converting the image; maybe this is another question.

Comment: Indeed, apologies for the sloppy pointer math. I've updated the answer to use byte-based arithmetic and fixed up the last parameter to `memcpy`.